# Create Continous uiimage animation in x axis

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uianimation

i want to create background like http://disqus.com/ continues background but i can't get it after try with my code like this

```
continuesBackground =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pattern"]];
    continuesBackground.frame=CGRectMake(0, 56, 320, 102);
    continuesBackground.layer.zPosition=100;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         continuesBackground.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 200);  }
                     completion:^(BOOL finish) {
                         continuesBackground.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(200, 0);

                     }];
```

how to make it ? do i need nstimer?

Comment: how didn't the code you provided work? What's the error you experienced?

Comment: no error in my code.. i jut want to create like disqus background wich have continousbackgorund view from left to right.. can ou help me?

Comment: instead of `(0, 200)`, transform it by (200, 0)` and it'll be shifted horizontally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (void)animateImageViewFromStartPosition:(CGPoint)aStartPosition toEndPosition:(CGPoint)aEndPosition; {
  CGRect oldFrame = CGRectMake(aStartPosition.x, aStartPosition.y, continuesBackground.frame.size.width, continuesBackground.frame.size.height);
  [continuesBackground setFrame:oldFrame];

  [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0f
                        delay:0.0f
                      options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                   animations:^(void){
                     CGRect newFrame = continuesBackground.frame;
                     newFrame.origin = aEndPosition;
                     continuesBackground.frame = newFrame;
                   }
                   completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     if(finished){
                       [self animateImageViewFromStartPosition:aStartPosition toEndPosition:aEndPosition];
                     }
                      }];
}
```

Then call the method in your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad; {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self animateImageViewFromStartPosition:CGPointMake(0.0f, 56.0f) toEndPosition:CGPointMake(320.0f, 56.0f)];
}
```

You can easily modify this to a transform, or whatever you want, and it will keep the animation going indefinitely. Hope that Helps!

Comment: hy msgambel... can u put some example of astartPosition and end startposition?

Comment: Sure. Use start point `CGPointMake(0.0f, 56.0f)`, and end point `CGPointMake(320.0f, 56.0f)`.

Comment: i've change your code...but why on line
continuesBackground.frame.origin = end; <-error expression not assignable

Comment: I've edited the code to be more explanatory. Just make sure that your `UIImageView` is already added as a subview *before* you call the method.

Comment: still error continuesBackground.frame.origin = aStartPosition; check my gist https://gist.github.com/4050250 pls check mycode

Comment: hi msGambel its already running but why it not continously? so like an disqus.com

Comment: Try it now. This should work for sure. I've compiled it and tested it myself.

Answer (score 1):

```
  - (void)animateImageViewFromStartPosition:(CGPoint)aStartPosition toEndPosition:(CGPoint)aEndPosition; {
   CGRect oldFrame = CGRectMake(aStartPosition.x, aStartPosition.y,continuesBackground.frame.size.width, continuesBackground.frame.size.height);
    [continuesBackground setFrame:oldFrame];

     [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0f
                    delay:0.0f
                  options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
               animations:^(void){
                 CGRect newFrame = continuesBackground.frame;
                 newFrame.origin = aEndPosition;
                 continuesBackground.frame = newFrame;
               }
               completion:^(BOOL finished){
                 if(finished){
                   [self animateImageViewFromStartPosition:aStartPosition toEndPosition:aEndPosition];
                 }
                  }];
 }
```

Then call the method in your viewDidLoad method:

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad; {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [self animateImageViewFromStartPosition:CGPointMake(0.0f, 56.0f) toEndPosition:CGPointMake(320.0f, 56.0f)];
   }
```

talking about this code please let me know where to apply an code for

Answer (score 0):

The following correct answer of the problem in Swift 4.2 version:

```
func animateImageViewFrom(startPosition aStartPosition: CGPoint, toEndPosition aEndPosition: CGPoint) {
        let oldFrame = CGRect(x: aStartPosition.x, y: aStartPosition.y, width: continuesBackground.frame.size.width, height: continuesBackground.frame.size.height)
        continuesBackground.frame = oldFrame

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            var newFrame = self.continuesBackground.frame
            newFrame.origin = aEndPosition
            self. continuesBackground.frame = newFrame
        }) { (finished) in
            if finished {
                self.animateImageViewFrom(startPosition: aStartPosition, toEndPosition: aEndPosition)
            }
        }
}
```